# How can I filter source XML and then pass the result on again as XML to process normally

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath-1.0

I have a xslt and xml processing workflow where the document is processed from the root match and then various other processing elements are triggered. I now need to take that same workflow and inject a pre processing step that will filter the data at one of the child levels and then continue processing as before.

**Current**
Input A (xmlA) -> Template (xslt1) = Output

**Pre Processing**
Input A (xmlA) -> Filter out unwanted data (xmlNEW) -> Template (xslt1) = Output (without filtered data)

I need to inject it before the handling of the document as there are way too many templates already in place that would break if I filtered the data further in the processing workflow.

I have the filter working in a separate test document , I just cannot get it to work when trying to use variables and params in template calls.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<MultiDocumentLevel>
    <DocumentLevel>
        <OrderLevel>
            <AllowedFormat>
                <HeaderLevel>
                    <HeaderSort>12345</HeaderSort>
                    <HeaderCode>12345</HeaderCode>
                </HeaderLevel>
                <HeaderLevel>
                    <HeaderSort>9999</HeaderSort>
                    <HeaderCode>9999-1</HeaderCode>
                </HeaderLevel>
                <HeaderLevel>
                    <HeaderSort>0000</HeaderSort>
                    <HeaderCode>0000</HeaderCode>
                </HeaderLevel>
                <HeaderLevel>
                    <HeaderSort>8989</HeaderSort>
                    <HeaderCode>8989</HeaderCode>
                </HeaderLevel>
                <HeaderLevel>
                    <HeaderSort>7777</HeaderSort>
                    <HeaderCode>123</HeaderCode>
                </HeaderLevel>
                <HeaderLevel>
                    <HeaderSort>123</HeaderSort>
                    <HeaderCode>14</HeaderCode>
                </HeaderLevel>
                <HeaderLevel>
                    <HeaderSort>1</HeaderSort>
                    <HeaderCode>1</HeaderCode>
                </HeaderLevel>
            </AllowedFormat>
        </OrderLevel>
    </DocumentLevel>
</MultiDocumentLevel>
```

Main Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="MultiDocumentLevel"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--    ****************************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!--        Name:           MultiDocumentLevel                                                                                           -->
    <!--                        Xsl's Main Template - Start of Builder                                                                                           -->
    <!--    ****************************************************************************************************************** -->
    
    <xsl:template match="MultiDocumentLevel">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="DocumentLevel/OrderLevel/AllowedFormat/HeaderLevel"/>
    </xsl:template> 

    <!--    ****************************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!--        Name:           HeaderLevel                                                                                    -->
    <!--                        Xsl's HeaderLevel Template - Process main data                                                 -->
    <!--    ****************************************************************************************************************** -->

    <xsl:template match="HeaderLevel">
        <!-- Process all nodes under HeaderLevel-->  
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(),'  -  ',HeaderCode,'  -  ',.)"/><br/>
    </xsl:template> 
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Filter Template

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="allowedheaders">
    <headers status="AllowedToPrint">
        <HeaderSort printHeader="12345" name="Allowed1"/>
        <HeaderSort printHeader="123" name="Allowed2"/>
        <HeaderSort printHeader="0000" name="Allowed3"/>
    </headers>
</xsl:variable>

    
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>   
    
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="HeaderLevel">  
                  <!-- filter the data at headerlevel based on lookup in allowedheaders variable -->
                    <xsl:if test="HeaderSort=msxsl:node-set($allowedheaders)/headers[@status='AllowedToPrint']/HeaderSort/@printHeader 
                    or HeaderCode=msxsl:node-set($allowedheaders)/headers[@status='AllowedToPrint']/HeaderSort/@printHeader">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired Output that can be used by additional templates and transforms :

```
<MultiDocumentLevel>
    <DocumentLevel>
        <OrderLevel>
            <AllowedFormat>
                <HeaderLevel>
                    <HeaderSort>12345</HeaderSort>
                    <HeaderCode>12345</HeaderCode>
                </HeaderLevel>
                <HeaderLevel>
                    <HeaderSort>0000</HeaderSort>
                    <HeaderCode>0000</HeaderCode>
                </HeaderLevel>
                <HeaderLevel>
                    <HeaderSort>7777</HeaderSort>
                    <HeaderCode>123</HeaderCode>
                </HeaderLevel>
                <HeaderLevel>
                    <HeaderSort>123</HeaderSort>
                    <HeaderCode>14</HeaderCode>
                </HeaderLevel>
            </AllowedFormat>
        </OrderLevel>
    </DocumentLevel>
</MultiDocumentLevel>
```

Comment: When you filter are you removing data that is used to set the variables? Without seeing any code XSLs and XML we are only guessing

Comment: Any XSLT 1 pipelining of intermediary nodes needs to make sure it uses `exsl:node-set` or similar to convert any intermediary RTF (result tree fragment) to a node set to be able to process it further with XSLT/XPath.

Comment: I have added in some dumbed down templates as there are over 9 templates linked in the "real" project I am working in.  The filter template will only show data that matches the allowedheaders variable, so if you compare Sample xml to the output of the filter template - you will see the difference. I basically need to then process this remaining xml with the main template. Have never done this before so not sure if it is at all possible to pass it via a param or if there is a better way to do it. Also - can only be done using v1.0 which is why the msxsl:node-set needs to be used.

Comment: Please add the expected result. The result I am getting after applying your 2 stylesheet does not seem right.

Comment: Added expected output

Comment: As outlined in the question details - the simplest way to describe this is... I need to pre-filter the source xml before parsing it with the rest of the stylesheet(s). I hope to do this upfront so that no other templates need  to change. There are more than 20000 lines of code in the project.

Comment: @MergatroidSA If you pre-filter the source into a variable, you will need to change at least some of the other templates so that they process the variable instead of the original input XML. Otherwise you would need to save the output of the filtering stylesheet to a file and process the result using the other stylesheet/s. Or use a pipelining application to do it for you.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I am just wanting to get to the point of filtering and then passing that onto the next template that is called. The way the templates are written they all get triggered from a master section within a main stylesheet so that is where I am hoping the changes will reflect. So far (perhaps because I am limited to ver 1.0) the variable store does not seem to contain the full xml source or I am missing the context somewhere. I have never done a pre filter and tried to insert it post development of the initial stylesheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a variable that contains the original XML document with only the disallowed `HeaderLevel` elements removed and then apply templates to this variable, you will need to build your stylesheet along these lines:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:variable name="allowedheaders">
    <headers status="AllowedToPrint">
        <HeaderSort printHeader="12345" name="Allowed1"/>
        <HeaderSort printHeader="123" name="Allowed2"/>
        <HeaderSort printHeader="0000" name="Allowed3"/>
    </headers>
</xsl:variable>


<!-- main template -->

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- pre-filter -->
    <xsl:variable name="filteredInput">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="filter"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- continue processing with the remaining templates -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($filteredInput)/MultiDocumentLevel"/>
</xsl:template>  


<!-- filtering templates -->

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="filter">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="filter"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>   
    
<xsl:template match="HeaderLevel" mode="filter">  
    <!-- filter the data at headerlevel based on lookup in allowedheaders variable -->
    <xsl:if test="HeaderSort|HeaderCode = msxsl:node-set($allowedheaders)/headers[@status='AllowedToPrint']/HeaderSort/@printHeader">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="filter"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template> 


<!-- remaining templates -->

<!-- all your remaining templates go here, for example: -->

<xsl:template match="HeaderLevel">
    <!-- Process all nodes under HeaderLevel-->  
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(),'  -  ',HeaderCode,'  -  ',.)"/><br/>
</xsl:template> 


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, you need to heed the warning given by @y.arazim: your "Main Template" stylesheet, as posted here, applies only one template.

Comment: Amazing ! Thank you. This works just as I was hoping. The important piece of info I was missing was applying a mode to the identity template which I did not know was possible. Everything works as expected so far in my testing.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to do something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:variable name="allowedheaders">
    <headers status="AllowedToPrint">
        <HeaderSort printHeader="12345" name="Allowed1"/>
        <HeaderSort printHeader="123" name="Allowed2"/>
        <HeaderSort printHeader="0000" name="Allowed3"/>
    </headers>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/MultiDocumentLevel">
    <!-- filter the data at headerlevel based on lookup in allowedheaders variable -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DocumentLevel/OrderLevel/AllowedFormat/HeaderLevel[HeaderSort|HeaderCode=msxsl:node-set($allowedheaders)/headers[@status='AllowedToPrint']/HeaderSort/@printHeader]"/>
</xsl:template>



<!--    ****************************************************************************************************************** -->
<!--        Name:           HeaderLevel                                                                                    -->
<!--                        Xsl's HeaderLevel Template - Process main data                                                 -->
<!--    ****************************************************************************************************************** -->

<xsl:template match="HeaderLevel">
     <!-- Process all nodes under HeaderLevel-->  
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), '  -  ', HeaderCode,'  -  ', HeaderSort)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I had to modify your `HeaderLevel` template as well as the output method to get a reasonable result, which with the provided input example will be:

```
1  -  12345  -  12345
2  -  0000  -  0000
3  -  123  -  7777
4  -  14  -  123
```

---

Please note that your "Main Template" stylesheet has a template that matches the root `MultiDocumentLevel` element and applies templates to the `HeaderLevel` descendant elements only:

```
<xsl:template match="MultiDocumentLevel">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DocumentLevel/OrderLevel/AllowedFormat/HeaderLevel"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This makes all the other templates except the one matching `HeaderLevel` redundant, since they will never be applied.

Comment: So the filtering is correct but the intended output would be the same as the input just filtered as per the items allowed through .

Comment: So I guess I don't understand what this is all about. Your 2nd stylesheet, the one you labeled "Filter Template",  already does exactly that (although it could be written more elegantly). I thought you want to combine the two styleheets into one.